# Extract column data from a simple text table

Tags: ruby, string, parsing

I got such stdout.

```
Queues
  queue                                          dur  autoDel  excl  msg   msgIn  msgOut  bytes  bytesIn  bytesOut  cons  bind
  ==============================================================================================================================
  14531c8d-dd9b-4f41-9d92-c1344774d21c:0.0            Y        Y        0     0      0       0      0        0         1     2
  qmfagent-425fa29c-0892-4c08-a2d9-e7331a37dc13       Y        Y        0     0      0       0      0        0         1     4
```

So I need to parse this output and get only something like this

```
14531c8d-dd9b-4f41-9d92-c1344774d21c:0.0
qmfagent-425fa29c-0892-4c08-a2d9-e7331a37dc13
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this ruby? Of course there could be more lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split lines by newline (`\n`). Get last two lines.

```
output = <<EOD
Queues
  queue                                          dur  autoDel  excl  msg   msgIn  msgOut  bytes  bytesIn  bytesOut  cons  bind
  ==============================================================================================================================
  14531c8d-dd9b-4f41-9d92-c1344774d21c:0.0            Y        Y        0     0      0       0      0        0         1     2
  qmfagent-425fa29c-0892-4c08-a2d9-e7331a37dc13       Y        Y        0     0      0       0      0        0         1     4
EOD

lines = output.strip.split("\n") # Split lines by newline
last_two_lines = lines[-2..-1] # Get the last 2 lines.
p last_two_lines.map {|line| line.split[0]} # Get the first fields.
```

prints

```
["14531c8d-dd9b-4f41-9d92-c1344774d21c:0.0", "qmfagent-425fa29c-0892-4c08-a2d9-e7331a37dc13"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queues = <<EOS
queue                                          dur  autoDel  excl  msg   msgIn  msgOut  bytes  bytesIn  bytesOut  cons  bind
==============================================================================================================================
14531c8d-dd9b-4f41-9d92-c1344774d21c:0.0            Y        Y        0     0      0       0      0        0         1     2
qmfagent-425fa29c-0892-4c08-a2d9-e7331a37dc13       Y        Y        0     0      0       0      0        0         1     4
EOS

queues.lines.each {|line|
  puts line.split.first if line =~ /[[\da-f]]{4}/i    # detects 4 consecutive hexadecimals
}
```